# JMockit MockUp persisting between Spock tests

Tags: groovy, spock, jmockit

I'm using a Spock test written in Groovy to test some Java code. I'm using JMockit to mock methods in the java code, as Spock only handles mocking Groovy classes. I'm running into a problem where a JMockit `MockUp` is persisting between tests. Such a mock instance should only exist for the test (per JMockit documentation), but this isn't working, and I imagine it's because it's not using the JMockit test runner, and rather the Spock test runner.

Here is the simplest example of the problem I'm facing. I have a simple method returning a string, I can change the return value of the method with `MockUp` but it still exists for the third test, which doesn't expect it to be used.

**Java Class**

```
public class ClassToTest {
    public String method() {
        return "original";
    }
}
```

**Spock Test**

```
class ClassToTestSpec extends Specification {
    void "first test"() {
        when:
        String result = new ClassToTest().method()

        then:
        result == "original"
    }

    void "second test"() {
        setup:
        new MockUp<ClassToTest>() {
            @Mock
            public String method() {
                return "mocked"
            }
        }

        when:
        String result = new ClassToTest().method()

        then:
        result == "mocked"
    }

    void "third test"() {
        when:
        String result = new ClassToTest().method()

        then:
        result == "original"
    }
}
```

The third test fails, because `ClassToTest.method()` still returns the String "mocked" rather than "original". Using a debugger I have validated that the Mocked method is called twice.

**Question**

Is there any way to manually remove a class `MockUp` in JMockit? Thanks.

Comment: Spock can mock both Java and Groovy classes. Mocking the class under test is a smell, and should be used with care.

Comment: Thanks for the response @PeterNiederwieser, I'm not able to use the normal notation, `instance.method() >> result`, can you point me in the proper direction?

Comment: Scratch that, the notation does work, I had forgotten to instantiate the object with `Mock`, such as `ClassToTest instance = Mock(ClassToTest)`. Now to figure out how to make this a partial mock, possibly with a Spy.

Comment: If you absolutely need/want a half-mock, `Spy()` is the way to go. Often it's better to refactor the code under test or reconsider what/how to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the MockUp.tearDown method on the created mockup object, to manually undo its effects.

Comment: Personally I have had no luck with the tearDown method in a spock test. If someone has gotten this working, I would like to see an example Specification. Thanks. As for now, I am avoiding Jmockit in spock.

Comment: As of JMockit 1.28 this answer is not valid anymore as `MockUp#tearDown` was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to the question - because I still don't know if JMockit's `MockUp` can be manually removed. But thanks to @PeterNiederwieser's comments, I found that you can actually create a partial mock for a Java class. Below is the change to the second test from above.

```
void "second test"() {
    setup:
    ClassToTest test = Spy(ClassToTest) {
        method() >> "mocked"
    }

    when:
    String result = test.method()

    then:
    result == "mocked"
}
```

Peter mentioned reconsidering how and what to test if a `Spy()` is necessary, but for my use case this is preferred.